# Camera2 on touch focus. Map TextureView onClick to sensorArraySize

Tags: java, android, touch-event, android-camera2

I have a camera that feeds its data into a AutoFitTextureview (across whole screen) that should focus the camera depending on where the user has touched the texture view. The resolutions of the camera and textureview are different. How do I transform the touch rectangle into a  MeteringRectangle. Tried the following code but it didn't work

```
   private View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener =new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            final int actionMasked = event.getActionMasked();
            if (actionMasked != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }
            Timber.d("Triggered mOnTouchListener");


            final Rect sensorArraySize = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
            Timber.d("Triggered mOnTouchListener");

            RectF touchRect = new RectF((event.getX() - 100),(event.getY() - 100), (event.getX() + 100), (event.getY() + 100));
            Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
            RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.setRectToRect(touchRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);


//This doesnt work   final int y = (int)((event.getX() / (float)view.getWidth())  * (float)sensorArraySize.height());
//            final int x = (int)((event.getY() / (float)view.getHeight()) * (float)sensorArraySize.width());
//            final int halfTouchWidth  = 150;
//            final int halfTouchHeight = 150;
//            MeteringRectangle focusArea = new MeteringRectangle(Math.max(x - halfTouchWidth,  0),
//                    Math.max(y - halfTouchHeight, 0),
//                    halfTouchWidth  * 2,
//                    halfTouchHeight * 2,
//                    MeteringRectangle.METERING_WEIGHT_MAX - 1);

            MeteringRectangle focusArea = new MeteringRectangle(rectFToRect(bufferRect), MeteringRectangle.METERING_WEIGHT_MAX - 1);

            cameraFocusIndicator.setHaveTouch(true, new Rect((int) (event.getX() - 100),(int) (event.getY() - 100), (int) (event.getX() + 100),(int) (event.getY() + 100)));
            cameraFocusIndicator.invalidate();
            Timber.d("Triggered setFocusMode");
            focusAreaTouch = focusArea;
            setFocusMode();
            return true;
        }

    };
```

Code for setFocusMode

```
  private void setFocusMode() {
    try {
        Timber.d("setFocusMode number of CONTROL_MAX_REGIONS_AF %s", mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_MAX_REGIONS_AF));

        if(mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_MAX_REGIONS_AF)==0)
            return;

        Timber.d("setFocusMode");
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

        Timber.d("setFocusMode"+focusAreaTouch);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, new MeteringRectangle[]{focusAreaTouch});
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Timber.e(e,"setFocusMode");
    }
}
```